# Wordpress sort posts by meta key

Tags: sorting, wordpress

I have to give up my trying. Not a Wordpress expert here, but try to solve a Wordpress problem.

I am using "I love it!" as my Wordpress website theme, and the theme provides a post love custom field that you could like posts. Currently I try to sort posts by number of the likes.

I got the `meta_key` which is `nr_like`, and the `meta_value`, then I used query post by

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'nr_like' ) );
```

HOWEVER, I don't know where should I put this into.... It should be in the loop, I just can't find it. I tested it in my index.php several times, but nothing happened.

Please could someone tell me how to solve this, I don't want to waste any more time on it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for @codemania 's updated.

Answer (score 2):

Use meta_value_num. This is because 'nr_like' might be a numerical value.

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
```

'meta_value' is for sorting strings (alphabetically)

Comment: Thank you, you are right! It is number of likes! Where should I put this into? New to Wordpress, I can't find the correct loop.... in index.php?

Comment: In the same code as you posted, like so $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'nr_like' ) );

Comment: I mean the $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'nr_like' ) ); whole thing..... I just can;t find the loop of my theme... Is it always in index.php?

Comment: Ofcourse you'd need other parameters to build a proper WP query.

Comment: Depends on the theme as to where the code is. It can be at multiple places. Usually in index.php, single.php

Comment: I have tried put "$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'nr_like' ) );" brefore "if(have...)"

Comment: Ok... I will try more. Thank you for your patience, maybe I am not explaining it very clearly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50107/discussion-between-carhill-and-jmdee)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `WP_Query` object you need to loop over it.

```
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

      // this is your loop

 endwhile;

 else:

      //no posts were found

 endif;

 //end of loop
```

Comment: Thank you, Max. I just can't find the that code in my theme.... so strange, only I have is that "if (have_posts()) { loop }"

Comment: have_posts() uses the default loop, set up through the global post object etc etc.

Comment: If you have a different WP_Query object you want to use (which you made in your question), you just run have_posts as a method on the object.

i.e `$query->have_posts()`, `$query->the_post()` etc